# inner join array result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join

Looking at this array, one can see that only the `foo6` value differs from each parent key:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [foo1] => Apple
          [foo2] => Banana
          [foo3] => Carrots
          [foo4] => Deer
          [foo5] => Feather
          [foo6] => Grapes
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
          [foo1] => Apple
          [foo2] => Banana
          [foo3] => Carrots
          [foo4] => Deer
          [foo5] => Feather
          [foo6] => Heater
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
          [foo1] => Apple
          [foo2] => Banana
          [foo3] => Carrots
          [foo4] => Deer
          [foo5] => Feather
          [foo6] => Quail Eggs
        )
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  tpp.page_master_properties_style AS foo1,
  tpp.page_master_properties_bg AS foo2,
  tpp.page_master_properties_data AS foo3,
  tpp.page_properties_style AS foo4,
  tpp.page_properties_bg AS foo5,
  tpp.page_properties_data AS foo6,
  tobj.objects_script AS foo6
FROM templates t
  INNER JOIN category tc
    ON t.category_id = tc.category_id
  INNER JOIN page_properties tpp
    ON t.templates_id = tpp.templates_id
  INNER JOIN objects tobj
    ON t.templates_id = tobj.templates_id
WHERE
  t.templates_id = ?
```

where `? = 1`

This is probably because Table **objects** has multiple entry for `templates_id`:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  objects_id  |  templates_id  |  objects_script |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|       1      |        1       |      Grapes     |
|       2      |        1       |      Heater     |
|       3      |        1       |     Quail Eggs  |
|       4      |        2       |       Milk      |
|       5      |        3       |       Lemon     |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I'm wondering is there any built-in mySQL function that can combine `foo6` into a singular array for example to achieve result like this:

```
Array
(
  [foo1] => Apple
  [foo2] => Banana
  [foo3] => Carrots
  [foo4] => Deer
  [foo5] => Feather
  [foo6] => Array
            (
              [0] => Grapes
              [1] => Heater
              [2] => Quail Eggs
            )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in the mysql arsenal:

```
SELECT
  tpp.page_master_properties_style AS foo1,
  tpp.page_master_properties_bg AS foo2,
  tpp.page_master_properties_data AS foo3,
  tpp.page_properties_style AS foo4,
  tpp.page_properties_bg AS foo5,
  group_concat(tpp.page_properties_data) AS foo6,
  tobj.objects_script AS foo6
FROM templates t
  INNER JOIN category tc
    ON t.category_id = tc.category_id
  INNER JOIN page_properties tpp
    ON t.templates_id = tpp.templates_id
  INNER JOIN objects tobj
    ON t.templates_id = tobj.templates_id
WHERE
  t.templates_id = ?
GROUP BY
  tpp.page_master_properties_style AS foo1,
  tpp.page_master_properties_bg AS foo2,
  tpp.page_master_properties_data AS foo3,
  tpp.page_properties_style AS foo4,
  tpp.page_properties_bg AS foo5
```

This will group all the rows in `tpp.page_properties_data` together into the only row of data and split them by commas - which you can then easily [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) into an array when you loop through the dataset.

Comment: Thanks! But this is confusing, should I create a new column for `page_properties_data`?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia No, not at all. Run your query and in the PHP explode that single Column into it's own array (as an element of the greater array for each row)